# How can I show Javascript code in WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to show javascript code in my webbrowsers in C#. Normally, When I navigated, browser wants to save it.. But I want browser shows it on browser's screen.. I think that I must do a javascript viewer with webbrowser..

I used like that code but it doesnt work (still asking to save..)

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://xxxx.com/aaa.js", "_mainframe");
```

Comment: change mime type to something like text/html

Comment: can i do it programmatically?

Comment: Kind of. If you write your own handler for *.js files and map it to .Net. Or you can change JS MIME type in IIS. Or just rename your *.js files to something like *.txt ;)

Comment: yep but its not my own js file.. and I want to do it programmatically.. maybe inject code to js file ? thank you

Comment: Retrieve JS file on the background (on the server end) and then write its content into your frame?

Comment: i did like that. but when js codes are very much, webbrowser cant show all of them.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a WebBrowser control for this but simply download it using a `HttpClient` and display it e.g. in a TextBox.

The WebBrowser control is basically an embedded IE which will download files if it thinks a file with that MIME type should be downloaded or if there are headers like `Content-disposition: attachment` (which force a download prompt in the browser).

Comment: thanx for answer but I want to use webbrowser to display it.. and how can I change mime type programmatically? I mean inject code to js code?